# Проблемы с printf scanf при работе с динамически созданным массивом char * в с++

Tags: c++, c, io

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n; scanf("%d", &n);
    char **str;
    str = new char* [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%s", str[i]);

    for (int i = n; i--;)
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
};
```

При запуске после ввода данных в массив программа просто вылетает. На windows 10 и компилятор MinGW g++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что вы неправильно выделили память. Вы выделили память только под количество слов, но для каждого слова необходимо также выделять память. Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n; scanf("%d", &n);
    char **str;
    str = new char* [n];
    char temp[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", temp);
        str[i] = new char[strlen(temp)+1];
        strcpy(str[i], temp);
    }

    for (int i = n; i--;)
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
};
```

Comment: Для каждой строки требуется выделять `strlen(temp)+1` для нуль-терминатора. `scanf("%s", temp);` следует ограничить по числу максимально считанных байт `scanf("%99s", temp);`. Во втором цикле - вы выходите за приделы массива.

Comment: @Artemy Vysotsky ну насчет +1 согласен, а насчет второго цикла вы неправы. Когда i станет равно нулю, цикл прекратится

Comment: а когда `i = n`?

Comment: i будет равно n только при инициализации переменной. При индексации в массиве первое значение будет n-1

Comment: признаю - был не прав.

Comment: @9Pasha Может во втором цикле условие лучше было написать как `i-- > 0`?

Comment: @zed Ну а какая разница? Компилятор пытается преобразовать выражение i-- в bool. А делает он это легко. Если число равно нулю - false, все остальные значения - true. То есть, пока i!=0 - условие будет выполняться

Comment: Ответ получился верный, но мне хотелось создать динамически массив в котором будут содержаться указатели на char, чтобы я мог выполнять присваивания таким образом `char *str; str  = "abcdefg"` только над массивом.

Comment: @ДаниилБатаев Если вы пишите на С++, то чем вас не устраивает тип `string`?

Comment: @9Pasha Это понятно, что компилятору без разницы. Я про то, что человеку, читающему этот код, надо его в голове расшифровывать. Но может мне это просто кажется, т.к. на Си я ещё не очень много писал.

Comment: @zed Меня он не устраивает тем что в нем есть куча всего еще и я не знаю как что там работает. Мне было оптимальней всего сделать очень просто без лишних вычислений как и было описано выше. Потому что мне очень важна производительность. Так же стало ясно что я не понял как работает то что я пытался сделать, что и послужило причиной задать вопрос.